# Angular stopped working after launch app on android device in Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

Angular stopped working after launch my app on real device. It was working perfectly while I was launching it on Ripple - Nexus emulator. After trying on android device it stopped working and now does not work even on emulators. Nothing in the code was changed. What could be the problem?

```
<body ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="myCtrl" >
<div class="app" ng-show="showMain">
    <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
    <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
        <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
        <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
    </div>
    <p>Input your name:</p>

</div>



<script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/Helper.js"></script>
```

JS:
var app = angular.module('myApp');

Comment: Please provide more information other than "stopped working". Did you look at the console log, did you use the chrome inspector to have a look?

Comment: Looked at the log: `Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module myApp ;`
Looks like angular module can't be enabled.

Comment: If you didn't change the code, it must be something in your environment - what did you change to run it on the real device? Did you modify config.xml? Did you install other cordova plugins? Can you look at your git history to see?